# Keep Sublime Text from opening duplicate tabs to a file?

Tags: tabs, sublime-text-3

I find it quite annoying when sublime opens a file in a new tab even if it was already opened in an existing tab. For example, say I have `main.cpp` open in a tab with a bunch of other files, I'm editing another file and go `ctrl+p` and `main RET` sublime would open `main.cpp` in another tab. There are other commands not just `ctrl+p`, for example `f4` after a build to take me to errors, if an error was `main.cpp` it would open it in a new tab.

Is there a way to disable that behavior?

**Edit:** I'm new to Sublime. It seems that this duplication of tabs behavior happens only with certain files. I can't figure out exactly why.

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/titoBouzout/PreventFakeClones/blob/master/PreventFakeClones.py

Go ahead and install this extension

Comment: If a total stranger walked up to you, handed you some unknown code, and told you to install it on your computer, would you do it?

Comment: Please quote the essential parts of the answer from the reference link(s), as the answer can become invalid if the linked page(s) change.